# Java. making a question re-ask if you get it wrong

Tags: java

I am new to java so I'm terrible at it. Basically I am making a multi choice quiz thing.

But my problem is that even if you get the question wrong it goes to the next question
and I want it to ask the same question again, like a loop. I have tried to make it work but I can't, it's probably very simple and easy.
If anyone can help that would be cool !

it says
whats 9+10?
 1. 19
 2. 21
 3. 18

current code:

```
iAnswer = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());

if (iAnswer == 1) {
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Correct");
}
else {
  iLives -= 1;
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("Incorrect");
}
```

(when you get a question wrong you lose a life, but i don't think that matters)

Comment: Could you please post your current code? What you have written already.So that we can see that and let you know what you can do.

Comment: "like a loop" that is literally what you want. This sounds like a 'do while' loop. You go through, get the answer and check if it is correct. Something like: 'do{ ...} while(!correct);'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you asked for but I came up with this !

```
 //get input from console
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 //create a loop to keep
    while (true) {
        //get 2 random number on value(0 - 20)
        int n1 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
        int n2 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
        //correct Answer is saved in correctAns value
        int correctAns = n1 + n2;
        System.out.println("What is the anwser of : ");
        System.out.print(n1 + " + " + n2 + " = ");
        //get the answer from user input
        int ans = scanner.nextInt();
        //if user input is equal to current Answer
        if (ans == correctAns) {
            System.out.println("Congrats next question !");
        } else {
            //if user input is not equal to currentAns
            boolean condition = true;
            //create another loop where user has to answer right to get to 
            //the next question
            while (condition) {
                System.out.println("What is the anwser of : ");
                System.out.print(n1 + " + " + n2 + " = ");
                ans = scanner.nextInt();
                //if user input is equal to currentAns
                if (ans == correctAns) {
                    //stop the loop and continue to the other question
                    condition = false;
                } else {
                    // if user input is not equal to currentAns keep asking
                    // the same question
                    condition = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be better not drop some code without explaination. Instead, it would help if you explained why and how this approach works.

Comment: When i answered  the question wasn't really understandable and I tried to give him an idea, this code is really easy to understand and that's why I didn't add explanation but I will edit it since he mentioned he is new